# Exiting an infinite loop with a key in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, while-loop, infinite-loop

i have an infinite loop that should be ended if i pressed any key. The program runs in linux. I have stumbled upon a function Here is a bit of my code :

```
int main(){
      While(1){
        ParseData(); //writing data to a text file
      }
return 0;
}
```

so i know that i can terminate the process by using ctrl + c in terminal, but it seems that it will interrupt the writing process so the datas are not written completely halfway through the process. I read that i need to use function from ncurses library , but i can't quite understand any.

Can someone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: "i can terminate the process by using ctrl + c in terminal, but it seems that it will interrupt the writing process so the datas are not written completely" - and what do you expect to happen when you press some key and handle it manually? The writing still may have not finished yet.

Comment: @lisyarus If the program handles it "manually" then it is possible to complete any operation if necessary. e.g. a file is written completely. With Ctrl+C you don't have a choice to decide when to terminate.

Comment: @harper "an infinite loop that should be ended if i pressed any key" - if the loop is forcibly ended, the data cannot be fully written either.

Comment: @lisyarus Obviously the OP asked how to change the code. Without the intention to change anything the code example wouldn't make sense. Instead you can see an idea to make a change: `function from ncurses library`, can't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare an `atomic_bool` and move your main loop to another thread. Now you can wait with a simple `cin`, once the user presses any key you exit your loop.

```
std::atomic_boolean stop = false;

void loop() {
    while(!stop)
    {
        ParseData(); // your loop body here
    }
}

int main() {

    std::thread t(loop); // Separate thread for loop.

    // Wait for input character (this will suspend the main thread, but the loop
    // thread will keep running).
    std::cin.get();

    // Set the atomic boolean to true. The loop thread will exit from 
    // loop and terminate.
    stop = true;

    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a key to exit a program that didn't finish writing to a file, even if you make the loop exits on key press it will interrupt the file writing too if not finished.

Why you just exit the loop when the data finishes writing to the file, like the following:

```
isFinished = false;      
While(!isFinished ){
    ParseData(); //writing data to a text file
   //after data finsihes
   isFinished = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

thread.cpp

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

std::atomic<bool> dataReady(false);

void waitingForWork(){
    std::cout << "Waiting... " << std::endl;
    while ( !dataReady.load() ){ 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }
    std::cout << "Work done " << std::endl;
}

int main(){

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::thread t1(waitingForWork);
  std::cout << "Press Enter to Exit" << std::endl;
  std::cin.get();

  dataReady= true; 
  t1.join();
  std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

g++ -o thread thread.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread

Answer (score -1):

The `C` way actually (include `conio.h` ):

```
char key;

while (1)
{
    key = _getch();

    // P to exit
    if (key == 'p' || key == 'P')
    {
        writer.close();
        exit(1);
    }
}
```